# 32650 LiFePO4 battery not charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, amperage, lifepo4

I have a problem charging my 32650 LiFePO<sub>4</sub> battery. I have connected it to a 3.6 V power supply with a 1 A limit. I also connected my multimeter to check the amperage to my battery. When I start charging, I notice that there is no amperage to my battery.

I then try to connect the power supply to my mini fan to check if there is a problem with the power supply. But the mini fan turns on without any problem. Then I checked the output voltage of the power supply, and it is 3.6 V. The battery voltage is 3.2 V when I try to charge it. I also tried connecting my mini fan to the battery to check if the battery is the problem, but it also can turn my fan on.

So can anybody help me to determine what is the cause for the battery not getting any amperage from my 3.6 V power supply?

Comment: Li batteries often come with protection circuits and something may be up with yours, but if your supply is trying to output 3.6V and the battery is drawing it to 3.2V with just wire between the power supply and the battery, then there is likely current...

Comment: Check your current meter with the fan as load. The fuse inside the multimeter may be blown.

Comment: What kind of power supply you mean? Are you sure it has a constant current limiting?

Comment: I say there is no current in my question, but actually there is but too little, only 0.05 A. So I think the fuse is still okay. About my power supply, actually I diy it using small step down buck converter that has maximum current of 2A. I connect this converter to USB plug that only supply maximum current of 1A. I set my small step down converter to output 3.6v only.